# Libraries/Tools for Website Parsing

Tags: hadoop, libraries, web-crawler

I would like to start working with parsing large numbers of raw HTML pages into semantic data structures.

Just interested in the community opinion on various available tools for such a task, particularly various useful libraries in any language.

So far, planning on using Hadoop to manage a lot of the processing, but curious about alternatives.

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse HTML into semantic data structures?'

Comment: Write programs that read a particular HTML page and pick out particular elements for storage in some native data structures.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download your page source and then create a DOM tree.
if you are coding in C# you can user the following tools to create your DOM tree.

1) http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ 
2) http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php

the first one is easy to use but second one is much faster and memory friendly and I suggest you to use the second one if you want to create a robust application

then you can extract usefull content from web page using:

http://www.chrisspen.com/blog/how-to-extract-a-webpages-main-article-content.html

and many other articles you can find to extract content from web page by Googling (extract main content from web page)

Hope it helps